# How do you increment a background position animation with Greensock/TweenLite?

Tags: gsap

I have an animation that I've sliced into 120 frames. Each frame is on a sprite. The sprite is made up of ten rows of twelve 100px x 100px frames. In order to create the animation I'm moving the background position of the sprite on a div in order, left to right, top to bottom.

I have to increment in steps of 100px to make the frame effect, so I can't just animate from a set left to right value (0 to 1000 px).

I assume I'm missing something simple about how the Greensock/TweenLite library works, because I can't seem to find a better way of doing this other than bluntly (with 120 lines of code):

```
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 0, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-100px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 1, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-200px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 2, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-300px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 3, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-400px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 4, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-500px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 5, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-600px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 6, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-700px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 7, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-800px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 8, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-800px'}});
new TweenLite('#selector', 1, {delay: 9, useFrames: true, css: {'background-position-x': '-900px'}});
```

Is there a simpler way to increment?

Comment: Can you set it up in a JSFiddle so we can have a play and see if there are more efficient ways to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you shouldn't use **background-position-x** as it is not widely supported.

There are a few options:

If your sprite sheet is laid out along one row only you can get away with using just **TweenMax** on it's own like this:

```
var frameWidth = 100, numCols = 12;
var steppedEase = new SteppedEase(numCols);

TweenMax.to('#selector', 6, {backgroundPosition: '-'+(frameWidth*numCols)+'px 0px', ease:steppedEase, repeat:-1});
```

If your sprite sheet is in the grid as you described in your question then you are going to have to bring in **TimeLineMax** to join all the tweens together like this:

```
var frameWidth = 100, frameHeight = 100, numCols = 12, numRows = 10;
var steppedEase = new SteppedEase(numCols-1);
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});

for(var i=0;i<numRows;i++){
    tl.add( TweenMax.fromTo('#selector', 0.5, { backgroundPosition:'0 -'+(frameHeight*i)+'px'}, { backgroundPosition: '-'+(frameWidth*(numCols-1))+'px -'+(frameHeight*i)+'px', ease:steppedEase} ));
}
```

Here are a couple of working fiddles I've created with a random sprite sheets I've found online to show this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Boolean/sV5Ug/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/sV5Ug/3/

---

A completely different option is to animate on the canvas using **CreateJS** with **Zoe**. Zoe allows you to export your animation as a sprite sheet and json files from a variety of tools (such as the Flash IDE). You would then use the BitmapAnimation class within CreateJS to turn the spritesheet image and json into an animation.

Demos and info here:

http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/spritesheet

http://www.createjs.com/#!/Zoe

Answer (score 0):

You can use TweenMax sprite plugin

https://github.com/spalt08/TweenSprite

```
TweenMax.spriteSheet( document.getElementById('selector'), {
    width: 1000,
    stepX: 100,
    stepY: 0,
    count: 9
}, 1.0);
```